# Use $query->set multiple times with pre_get_posts?

Tags: hooks

I am using *pre_get_posts hook* in order to filter posts by custom terms. All working fine, but if i want to filter posts by 2 custom terms, the query only filters by the last term given. See my code below. I hook this into *pre_get_posts* but when both if statements are TRUE, only the last $query->set is done, meaning it won't filter the posts twice. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks

```
//For searching
if( $query->is_main_query() && isset( $_GET[ 'ls' ] ) ) {
$rt_term_id = $_GET['listing_soort'];
$rt_term_id_land = $_GET['listing_land'];
        // IF our soort vakantie is set and not empty - include it in the query
        if( isset( $rt_term_id ) && ! empty( $rt_term_id ) ) {
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array( array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'vakantiesoorten_listing',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array($rt_term_id[0]),
            ) ) );
        }
        // IF our land vakantie is set and not empty - include it in the query
        if( empty($_GET['location_geo_data']) && isset( $rt_term_id_land ) && ! empty( $rt_term_id_land ) ) {
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array( array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'landen_listing',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array($rt_term_id_land[0]),
            ) ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of this pseudo code

```
if sky == blue
  set a = 5
if grass == green
  set a = 7
```

What value will `a` have? Not 12.

This is the exact same situation. You are setting a specific parameter to a specific value. In the second call, you are overwriting your previous value. To avoid this, you can build the value (here the array) beforehand, and call `->set()` only once.

```
$tax_query = array();
if( isset( $rt_term_id ) && ! empty( $rt_term_id ) ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'vakantiesoorten_listing',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => array($rt_term_id[0]),
    );
}
if( empty($_GET['location_geo_data']) && isset( $rt_term_id_land ) && ! empty( $rt_term_id_land ) ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'landen_listing',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => array($rt_term_id_land[0]),
    );
}
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I understood the why, just not the how.. This makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: One more question, to be sure; `$query->set( 'tax_query')` respects search variables, other than taxonomies, that are already in the search string right? So if someone is doing a text search and filters it with a custom term, the text search is respected, correct? Thanks

Comment: @RobbTe Yes. You can look at [a sample WP Query object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Sample_WP_Query_Object). Since you are only (over)writing the `tax_query`, this will have no influence on the other search variables

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, you just need to get the original value of the tax query, add the additional query, then set it again. The abbreviated version is:

```
// Get current tax query if it exists, otherwise get an empty array.
$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' ) ?: array();

if ( true ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(); // Add first tax query.
}

if ( true ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(); // Add second tax query.
}

$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query ); // Set tax query parameter on query.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I guess i understand your logic, but how do i set the 2 filters at `//ad first tax query` and `//add second tax query`. I mean i have to filter them for the term_id given right? Please further elaborate.